# Taking screenshot only attaches white image in iOS 8 Using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: ios, objective-c

in iOS 6 &  7 this works fine, but in iOS 8 it takes a screenshot of a white screen when I attach the image.

Oddly, if I cancel, then retry, it works fine..

This is the code;

```
   [savingPhotoAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0   animated:YES];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you cancel? is it a kind of alertView? you have to specify when taking the screenshot(afterScreenUpdates= YES).

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: It is a post to twitter feature, whereby the image is attached, using the SLComposeViewController so it offers a 'cancel' and 'post' button, if I try to post the image, I can see a white screen attachment, however if I cancel it, and try again, it works fine, and will continue working. I am not sure where the code you put above fits in my project... As I cannot put that inside the twitter posting code.

Comment: try to use [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]; it seems to be only a different way of getting screenshot.